# Using "array-includes" instead "includes" in javascript function to skip problem in IE11

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, es5-shim

I'm writing an application in `ASP.net`. I'm also using Bootstrap 3 framework.
Now `bootstrap-table.min.js` use

```
f(!h.includes(e))....
```

This provokes in Internet Explorer 11 an exception and suggest to use indexOF. In Firefox and Chrome all is ok.

A solution is to modify function and use `.array-includes` in place of `.includes` but to do this i need of nd an environment shimmed.

Anyway i've tried to use `airbnb-js-shims` Version Badge.
I don't understand how i've to use this shim.

I've installed `airbnb-js-shims` (Visual Studio 2013 Package Console
) with command

`npm i airbnb-js-shims`

but i receive the following message

```
  npm.cmd : npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
In row:1 car:4
+ npm <<<<  i airbnb-js-shims
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm notice crea...mmit  this file.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 npm
   WARN
    SupportPRJ No description
npm
   WARN
    SupportoPRJ No repository field.
npm
   WARN
    SupportoPrj No license field.
```

Command `npm i airbnb-js-shims` has created a folder called `node_modules` and inside this there're many subfolders (`airbnb-js-shims`, `array.prototype.flat` etc...)

On website is written 
Just `require/import airbnb-js-shims`, and the environment will be shimmed"

`import 'airbnb-js-shims';`

I don't understand where i've to put this command in `.js` file or anywhere else ?

I put this command in a `.js` but i receive an exception of syntax error.

Thanks in advance for your precious support and I apologize for my lack of knowledge with this type of environment.

Comment: Why don't you just use the polyfill in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill)?

Comment: Thans i followed your suggest. Thanks.